According to scripture can an atheist fully disbelieve in God?
The scripture does say that a person can deny the existence of God in their hearts, which I take to mean a ‘sincere disbelief’ not just the claim of disbelief:

14 The fool says in his heart, “There is no God.”
They are corrupt, they do abominable deeds;
there is none who does good. (Psalm 14 ESV)

However, in many other places of scripture, it seems to declare that God’s basic nature is declared in a self-evident way.

Therefore is there such a thing as a real ‘pure atheist’ or is that just an imaginary person?
Is there anything in scripture that clarifies the tension between self-evident truth and the fool’s ability to deny that evidence?
To what degree is the denial possible?
Is there even such a thing as a real atheist?


I remember, as a student atheist, having to argue this point with an agnostic room-mate. I still don't understand what is achieved in debate by questioning whether "real" atheists exist.

@StephenDisraeli - Maybe the only value is not closing our minds to the ideas of others?

The expression saying something in ones heart does not seem to imply that a person then also automatically truly believes it in his heart.
However, it does also exclude this possibility. If we equate 'truly believing', with 'believing in ones heart', one can say that the heart can be deceived, by others or by one self.

Jeremiah 17:9-10 The heart is deceitful above all things, and
desperately sick; who can understand it? “I the Lord search the heart
and test the mind, to give every man according to his ways, according
to the fruit of his deeds.
Hebrews 3:10 Therefore I was provoked with that generation, and said,
‘They always go astray in their heart; they have not known my ways.’

So the heart can be deceived or astray. But maybe the only ones who could ever truly know if a person truly does not believe in a god, or is only trying or pretending not to believe in a god. Are the person themselves and God. And maybe we can not even be sure if the person understands it themselves truly.
However, would sincery not believing be any excuse?

Proverbs 16:2 All the ways of a man are pure in his own eyes, but the
Lord weighs the spirit.


Jeremiah 20:12 O Lord of hosts, who tests the righteous, who sees the
heart and the mind, let me see your vengeance upon them, for to you
have I committed my cause.


Matthew 22:37 And he said to him, “You shall love the Lord your God
with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.

Maybe God keeps each person in a matter responsible for what beliefs they choose to cultivate in the heart and mind, and their actions as a consequence. It seems reasonable that one can only be judged about things where one would have the possibility to make a choice. And in a way probably most people have the choice to believe in a god or not. But just to be sure you can ask them that question: Did you choose to be an Atheist?
